# run query with button in access

Tags: jquery

have a query, and as the criteria for one of the fields I have it referencing a drop box I made in a form. It works: I can open the form, select my option, go to my query, click run, and it all works fine.

But now I want to put a Run Query button onto my form, so that others can easily use it without going to the actual query to click run.
I used the Command Button - selected Miscellaneous,
Run Query, clicked the correct query, and gave it text and a title.

However, when I go to my form and press this new Run Query button, query run but empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Hint: Show code

Comment: Are you asking about Microsoft Access?

Comment: yes. this is about Access 2010